# Использование package в @xml (JAXB)

Tags: xml, jaxb

Пишу код и потребовалось использовать поле package,  это слово зарезервировано в Java, а мне именно такое поле надо передавать в @xml схеме(пишу с помощью JAXB).
Как можно сделать package не "Java" версии ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете в поле использовать любое имя, а в аннотации маппинга указать, как оно должно выглядеть в XML. Например:

```
private String packageName;

@XmlAttribute(name = "package")
public String getPackageName() {
    return packageName;
}

public void setPackageName(String name) {
    this.packageName = name;
}
```

С `@XmlElement` симметрично.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но у меня почему так не переименовывается, только если делаю через `@XmlRootElement(name  = "elementName");`

Если знаете, можете подсказать почему?

Comment: @sank Создайте/расшарьте на GitHub или где ещё [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)-проект, я посмотрю.